# page.evaluate runs for hours

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to crawl the contents of a website and it works most of the time (finishes in minutes) but sometimes it takes up to 8 hours. I've managed to pinpoint the issue and it is fired in the page.evaluate part. Looking at the website in headless mode=false it just loads infinitely (after a click). Also if I manually try "document.querySelector" on that page that is stuck in loading, it works for me.

The code is the following:

```
    console.log("Test");
    let value = await page.evaluate((sel) => {
        let element = document.querySelector(sel);
        return element? element.innerHTML: null;
    },selector);
    console.log("Test2");
```

What can I do to prevent it from running that long (I would try to setup some kind of timeout system for this case)?
Or how could I track the time while the code is in this part? The code immediately after this part never runs (only after hours) probably because of the await.

Comment: Which site is this? The exact site behavior and your goals are important here. For example, if your data is available without waiting for the load event, `page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"}` can speed things up. If you're navigating with `networkidle0` but long-running connections are open, you may be blocked on that. Consider blocking external resources or disabling JS if that's not relevant to the action you're performing or the data you wnat to scrape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `await page.waitForSelector(sel, { waitUntil:timeout })` first then evaluate

Comment: It partly works. I can manage timeouts with waitforselector, but if I try to reload the page with await page.evaluate(() => {
                               location.reload(true);
                            });
It is stuck again. How can I refresh the website or somehow make page.evaluate usable again? (manually refreshing with location.reload(true) while the code is stuck works)
Should I post a new question regarding this?