# Puppeteer page.evaluate does not reach the website

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I had a problem with a long-time loading webpage that is partially solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72821385/page-evaluate-runs-for-hours).
If I try to reload the page with

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
   location.reload(true);
});
```

It is stuck again. It seems like nothing that I'd do with page.evaluate goes through to the browser while it is in this loading state. Manually refreshing in headless mode=false with location.reload(true) while the code is stuck works.
How can I refresh the website or somehow make page.evaluate usable again?

Edit: The website loads for a long time after a click on a next page button. It does not always happen, but only a very few times.

Comment: What site is this?

Comment: Sorry, but I do not see how that is relevant and the question has been also answered perfectly. Have a nice day!

Comment: It's relevant because every site works differently. "Edit: The website loads for a long time after a click on a next page button. It does not always happen, but only a very few times." is testament to this. The standard for help is a [mcve], but without the exact behavior of the page you're working on, it's impossible to create a complete, runnable, verified, robust answer. But sometimes answerers are able to take a lucky guess and solve the problem. It's not the common case, though, and there is probably a better way to achieve whatever you're trying to achieve.

Comment: For example, depending on the page and what you hope to achieve, `page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"})` may be a better solution. The default resolver for `goto` is `waitUntil: "load"`, which is a much stricter threshold because it blocks on resources you may not need. See [this antipattern explanation](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#never-using-domcontentloaded). Now, I can't guarantee that's a better answer because I don't know what we're dealing with here or what your goals are.

Comment: Other times, the site behavior sends you to a captcha, ad, popup, banner, extra loading screen, A/B test, etc, and you may be able to detect this specifically in a more robust way than `try`/`catch` and `location.reload`. But there's no way to know. One can only guess, hindering the quality of answers and the post's usefulness to future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not recommended, if it is to reload after a timeout, you can

```js
try {
      await page.goto(url, {timeout: 10000});
} catch (e) {
      console.log("time out , reload!");
      await page.reload(url);
      await page.evaluate(() => {
         ......
      });
}
```

Comment: This has worked perfectly with the added code of url=page.url(); storing current url beforehand, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

just to make sure test this.

```
    await page.evaluate(() => {
       window.location.reload(true);
    });
```

or

```
   await page.evaluate(() => {
       document.location.reload(true);
    });
```

Comment: I've tested window.location.reload(true); and it did not work I would have guessed the same for the other one, but i've tested nano's answer next, and it has worked. Thank you for the help anyways!